# need basic setup to test a website on real android device (chrome browser) using ruby appium framework

Tags: ruby, appium

I am trying to setup a basic framework with Cucumber, Appium and Ruby. I am getting errors when I run the basic script. I am testing web app on chrome browser for Android device. I can't figure out what's wrong with the setup. Appium Desktop for windows is running in the background
(Appium v1.12.1)

My env.rb

```
require "appium_lib"

def caps
  {caps:
       {
    deviceName: "Android_Device",
    platformName: "Android",
    browserName: "Chrome",
    newCommandTimeout: "3600"
         }
  }
end

Appium::Driver.new(caps, true)
Appium.promote_appium_methods Object
```

My hooks.rb file

```
Before do
  $driver.start_driver
end

After do
  sleep 3
  $driver.driver.quit
end
```

My Step Definition file

```
Given(/^I log on to the site with the following:$/) do |table|
  p "it works"
end
```

My feature file

```
Given I log on to the site with the following:
|site|
|ABC|
```

I am expecting the feature/scenario to pass

Actual Result-

```
C:\Users\Documents\xyz\abc (master)
λ cucumber features\Simple_POC.feature --tags @run
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
Unable to load the EventMachine C extension; To use the pure-ruby reactor, require 'em/pure_ruby'
cannot load such file -- 2.5/rubyeventmachine (LoadError)
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/rubyeventmachine.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7-x64-mingw32/lib/eventmachine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/faye-websocket-0.10.7/lib/faye/websocket.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.0.4/lib/appium_lib_core/common/ws/websocket.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.0.4/lib/appium_lib_core/common.rb:21:in `require_relative'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.0.4/lib/appium_lib_core/common.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.0.4/lib/appium_lib_core.rb:18:in `require_relative'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib_core-3.0.4/lib/appium_lib_core.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib-10.2.0/lib/appium_lib/appium.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib-10.2.0/lib/appium_lib.rb:10:in `require_relative'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib-10.2.0/lib/appium_lib.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
C:/Users/Documents/xyz/abc/features/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:144:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:85:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `each'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:272:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:68:in `run!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

was able to resolve the issue by doing the following -

1) gem uninstall eventmachine
2) gem install eventmachine --platform ruby

Tried few other solutions but the only one which worked are the above 2 steps.

Might help someone in the future